# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys..{}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, mongoose-populate

I am trying to get the posts of users that a login user has followed.

here is the backend code.

```js
router.get("/posts",checkAuth,async(req,res,next)=>{
    let user;
    let loginUserId=req.user.id;
    try{
        user=await User.findById(loginUserId);
   }
   catch(err){
       console.log(err);
       const error=new HttpError("Couldnt able to find People",500);
      return next(error);
   }
//    console.log(user)

   let followingsPosts=user.followings;


    let posts= await Post.find({creator:{$in:followingsPosts}}).populate("creator");

    console.log(posts);
   
    res.json(posts);
//    res.json(numFruits[0]);
});
```

then I send this posts array to my actionHandler file

```js
export const getPeoplePosts = () => (dispatch,getState) => {
  dispatch(setPostsLoading());
  axios
    .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/people/posts`,tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res=>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PEOPLE_POSTS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

then this action dispatched to reducer file

```js
//state of reducer file
const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    peoplePosts:[],
    loading: false
  };
  
  case GET_PEOPLE_POSTS:
          return {
            ...state,
            peoplePosts:       [...action.payload],
            loading: false
          };
```

then i am getting the error.

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

32 | axios
33 |   .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/people/posts`,tokenConfig(getState))
34 |   .then(res=>

> 35 |     dispatch({
> | ^  36 |       type: GET_PEOPLE_POSTS,
> 37 |       payload: res.data
> 38 |     })

Comment: when i remove the populate function from the backend code it works fine but i also want the creator details therefore i have to populate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the mistake,lol
I an trying to print the creator in the react because previously it was a id of creator, but after populating the creator i am getting the object.